# How to "connect dots" on top of an image using PHP

Tags: php, image

I have created a CMS where users can rate ten different categories on a scale from 1-10. When they are done I want to use the data to create an image showing the scores mapped out in a star. The "star" is generic, so it is just a .jpg image. So the trick is to plot in the ten different scores onto the image of the star. The combo of the image of the star and the scores should then be saved as a jpg on the server in order to show it to the user.

So before the image will just look like this:
http://junique.dk/star-before.jpg

And after the image will look like this:
http://junique.dk/star-after.gif

Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: accept the best answer as a sign of appreciation and to help other users to be able to find the best answer quicker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [GD](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to achieve this.

1. First you need to load the image, which can be done using [`imagecreatefromjpeg`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php). (It'd be preferable if you had the image as a png instead, as it's more suitable for simple drawings. If you do that, you need to use [`imagecreatefrompng`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefrompng.php) instead, naturally)
2. Then you draw lines between the centres of the relevant circles using [`imageline`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.imageline.php). You'll need to calculate these positions yourself, for instance by finding them in your image editor.
3. Finally you output it using for instance [`imagepng`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) (preferred) or [`imagejpeg`](http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php). Remember to set the proper content type, as shown in the examples on the page.

Comment: thanks - really good input. How do I save the image on the server afterwards?

Comment: @user1009409: If you look at the documentation of `imagepng` or `imagejpeg`, you can see that you can specify a filename if you wish to save to a file.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to create an array holding each x|y coordinate of every star. Then you can use phps [imageline](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageline.php) to draw a line from each star. Do this for every connection and you are done. A bit of knowledge of the GD library is recommended!

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called a [Kiviat diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radar_chart), also known as web chart, spider chart, star chart, star plot, cobweb chart, irregular polygon, polar chart, or radar chart.

I'm sure you'll find a php graphing library using these keywords, e.g. JpGraph's [radar plots](http://jpgraph.net/features/gallery.php#rader1).